# check if nested checkboxes are triggered using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 2 divs with check boxes nested in each. I basically would like to trigger an alert if a checkbox is clicked in the 1st one and second one, but I cannot seem to reach that scope. The checkboxes are classes.

```js
if ($("#result1 .tb2:checked").length == 1 && ($("#result2 .tb4:checked").length == 1  ) {
    alert("both clicked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">
<input type="checkbox" class="tb1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br><input type="checkbox"class="tb2" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br><br></div><br>
    
</div>
    
    
    
 <div id="result2">
<input type="checkbox" class="tb3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br><input type="checkbox"class="tb4" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br><br></div><br>
    
</div>
```

Comment: When are you running that Javascript code? It needs to be in an event handler, like `$(":checkbox").change()`.

Comment: As i understand your expected behaviour, you want to check that at least one checkbox is checked in each `div`, is it?

Comment: For instance, i need it to check if the yes in result 1 and the yes in result 2 has been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the test inside an event handler, so it will run whenever the checkboxes are changed.

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  if ($("#result1 .tb2").is(":checked") && $("#result2 .tb4").is(":checked")) {
    $("#output").text("both clicked");
  } else {
    $("#output").empty();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="tb1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="tb2" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<br>

</div>


<div id="result2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="tb3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="tb4" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<br>

</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it only works for the first div. You should use the `each` method to iterate over both divs

Comment: What do you mean? I specify the div IDs explicitly in the selectors, just like in the question.

Comment: What if i want to place this code in the document ready event instead of :checkbox selector?

Comment: Why would you do that? That will just run when the page loads, before the user has had a chance to check any of the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a button, and bind the `click` event handler to it. You iterate through both divs with `each` and count the number of checked items. For this, you can use the `:checked` selector.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("div").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find("input:checked").length === 2) {
            alert("Both checked");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjygn4t1/